# Cannot input the second line of numbers in c++

Tags: c++

I don't konw what happened that I can't input the second line of numbers unless the numbers I input are all type `int`. Perhaps there is something wrong with the data type. I always get the result half of which is the error codes for example `-858993460`. However, when I input all `1`s, it goes right. Since I can't search for something useful in the Internet, I wish that someone could solve this problem (or just answer my ignorant question). I'll appreciate it if somebody can help.
Thank you in advance.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Building {
public:
    int m_nFloor;
    int m_nRoom;
    double m_fArea;
    Building(int, int, double);
};
Building::Building(int floor, int room, double area) {
    this->m_nFloor = floor;
    this->m_nRoom = room;
    this->m_fArea = area;
}

class Housing :public Building {
public:
    int m_nBedRoom;
    int m_nBathRoom;
    Housing(int, int, double, int, int);
};
Housing::Housing(int floor, int room, double area, int bedroom, int bathroom):
    Building(floor,room,area)
{
    this->m_nBedRoom = bedroom; 
    this->m_nBathRoom = bathroom;
}

class Office :public Building {
public:
    int m_nFireFighter;
    int m_nTelephone;
    Office(int, int, double, int, int);
};
Office::Office(int floor, int room, double area, int firefighter, int telephone) :
    Building(floor,room,area)
{
    this->m_nFireFighter = firefighter;
    this->m_nTelephone = t

int main() 
{
    int floor1, room1, bedroom, bathroom;
    short area1;
    int floor2, room2, firefighter, telephone;
    short area2;
    cin >> floor1 >> room1 >> area1 >> bedroom >> bathroom;
    cin >> floor2 >> room2 >> area2 >> firefighter >> telephone;
    Housing hou(floor1, room1, area1, bedroom, bathroom);
    Office Off(floor2, room2, area2, firefighter, telephone);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no *second line* of input... What was the input that gave you problems? How do oyu know that input are wrong, etc.

Comment: You're calling `cin` on variables of type `int` or `short`, so if you input a value that is not of that type, `cin` will go into an error-state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a single data type for such problems unless its a solid requirement to have `short` and regular `int` seperately for specific variables.

Ordinally, you can also define a macro pre-hand to avoid re-writing the data types each time you want to change them:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include DT unsigned long int 
// change data type as per your requirement above.
.
.
.
int main() 
{
    DT floor1, room1, bedroom, bathroom, area1, floor2, room2, firefighter, telephone, area2;
    std::cin >> floor1 >> room1 >> area1 >> bedroom >> bathroom;
    std::cin >> floor2 >> room2 >> area2 >> firefighter >> telephone;
    Housing hou(floor1, room1, area1, bedroom, bathroom);
    Office Off(floor2, room2, area2, firefighter, telephone);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to have easier repro, change cin to ifstream, create your data in a file and experiment that way. Then, if you encounter a problem, post the data here.

It will also help you to debug the case, together with the community here.
Using cin does not give us idea what are you entering, which means in case you enter a non-number, it will fail, even if your code is right.

Comment: Okay, well,i think i find the mistake.It seems like that i forgot to change from "short" to "double".Thank you any way.

Comment: Well, this could be the case, if you were typing double values in cin :).